# How do I update libc and libstdc++ on OS X 10.5?

Tags: macos, macports, libc, darwin, libstdc++

I am using a Mac Mini as a build agent and I need to upgrade the standard libraries. I can't find either libc or libstdc++ on MacPorts.

Comment: What makes you think you need to do this ?

Comment: @Paul R: see the question that prompted my need to upgrade: [Why isn't Darwin's strtod thread-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527391/why-isnt-darwins-strtod-thread-safe)

Comment: If you're using MacPorts then they have gcc versions up to 4.6, which presumably includes the latest and greatest libc/libstdc++ et al?

Comment: Yes, I did try GCC 4.2, but that used the same libc/libstdc++ as GCC 4.0.1. I also tried GCC 4.4 and that DOES seem to have an updated libc/libstdc++ but it's evidently not new enough because I still got strtod bus errors. I didn't try GCC 4.6 - even if it worked I don't want my project to require that new of a toolset to work!

Comment: Well you could always split the difference and try gcc 4.5 (4.5.3 is on MacPorts).

Comment: Did you try the method stated here: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/LibcxxOnOlderSystems

Comment: If this can help you. https://lists.macports.org/pipermail/macports-dev/2015-January/029317.html